# Fixed width for table first column

Tags: html, css

I have a basic table with scrollable body. Doing that I had to set thead and tbody display:block and I also set the width for th and td.

For some reason the first column th doesn't line up with the first column tds.
Can anyone tell me what causes that?

CSS

```
 thead,
 tbody {
  display: block;
 }

 thead {
  text-align: left;
 }

 tbody {
  background: yellow;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 6em;
 }

 thead th,
 tbody td {
  width: 4em;
  padding: 2px;
 }

 thead tr th:first-child,
 tbody tr td:first-child {
  width: 8em;
  background: salmon;
  font-weight: normal;
 }
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karin/9poumsyp/#&togetherjs=nM5PwPmcVe)

Comment: do you mean, when content is more, first th takes more size than first td's right?

Comment: I want to keep first th and first td in a same width whatever the content

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The width property for `DIV` & `TABLE` works differently.

Use `max-width` & `min-width` to achieve the results you want:

```
thead tr th:first-child,
tbody tr td:first-child {
  width: 8em;
  min-width: 8em;
  max-width: 8em;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

**Edit:**

*(Editing the answer clarify the working of width in HTML, please point out if I got something wrong or missed anything!)*

In divs the width property is used to define the size of the element and the content is fitted in accordingly, irrespective of parent and sibling width.

But in the case of a table, the size of an element is calculated according to content, and the width property gets a lower priority. Even sibling size is taken into consideration. Thus we have to use additional properties, like `min-width` and `max-width` to force the size we want!

Comment: I have tested setting max-width but it does not change anything.

Comment: Updated my answer, forgot to mention min-width attribute, which is required when content not overflowing the with of 8em!