# Weird behavior when a fixed-width div is inside a td

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is the code I'm talking about:

```css
.box {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is how it looks like when running it on Chrome 75:

http://jsfiddle.net/o198cx7j/

[image: weird-width-size]

Why is the first column growing up so much? If I remove the fixed-width from`div`, it comes back to normal:

[image: normal]

In first place, **why is this happening?** Second, how can I make this work? 
I would like to have a fixed-width `div` inside a `td` and it must behave just like if you were using non-fixed-width `div`.

I know it is possible **moving the fixed-width out of the `div` to the `td`** or using **CSS grid** but I'm looking for an *alternative solution* using *tables*.

Comment: I think if you follow this: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#auto-table-layout you will get your answer

Comment: I don't understand " If I remove the fixed-width div, it comes back to normal"... If you remove the div, where does the purple come from in the subsequent image?

Comment: typo... sorry for that I meant: 'If I remove the fixed width from div, it comes back to normal'.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is doing this is because of this line: `<table width="100%"`. The table cell width algorithm reads the fixed width of 180px and expands the first cell proportionately with its contents (I'm not exactly sure why). If you remove the width attribute and add a 100% width to the second cell, you can keep the fixed width of the box and retain the dimensions.

```css
.second_cell{
   width: 100%;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr height="200px">
    <td>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="second_cell">Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to symlink's answer, you could also specify each td to have a 50% width.

---

Regarding why that's happening, I also agree with symlink's answer, but I'd like to add some info about the spec:

This proportional thing is how table works by spec (despite in some points the spec use words like "may", browsers  should follow the spec, having their own variances when its vague).

> However, if the table does not have a fixed width, user agents must receive all table data before they can determine the horizontal space required by the table. Only then may this space be allotted to proportional columns.

Further info can be found in the spec: [Calculating the width of columns](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.4)

So, without the div with fixed width, both columns have the same content width of "123" and hence they'll have a 50%/50% proportional width. And having 180px vs the width of "123" it'll proportionally distribute the width between the columns. If we change from 180px to 90px, the proportion changes. If we change from "123" to "12345" in the right column, the proportion changes as well.

Comment: That spec might be accurate in some places but has been superseded by https://drafts.csswg.org/css-tables-3/, despite the warning at the bottom that it's not ready for implementation. There are some deviations from css-tables-3 by various rendering engines but I think all the behavior specified there is implemented by at least one engine. Just FYI :)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, `width=""` is no longer supported as a table tag attribute. Set width with CSS instead.

As to your sizing question, table sizing works differently than div sizing. The solution in this question should work for you:

[Fixed width for table first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213703/fixed-width-for-table-first-column)